# Stream sound source via audio element and then web audio api

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, web-audio-api

Can we somehow get radio stream via audio element and do some work with web audio api?

So, "Website A" getting radio stream from "SERVER B", and then via web audio api doing their own stuff.

Error always appearing, "(index):1 Failed to load http://someserverb.com/track.mp3: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://somemywebsiteA.com' is therefore not allowed access."

So main question is, how to enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin?
Will be here some security problems?

Comment: You can't enable it, only the remote "server B" can determine that. If they choose not to respond with that header, you'll need to stream the resource through your server to your clients.

Comment: Thanks, for answer! I understand your explanation. Maybe someone have other answers?

Answer (score 0):

The  Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a Server Problem...
Please see CORS for more details => f.e. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing